# Passar dados no construtor php pra classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma dúvida de como enviar os dados para a criação de um objetivo, li em alguns tutoriais que era apenas colocar deste modo em PHP4:

```
$elo1=new Elo(1300);
$elo1->fc_Elo();
```

Porem do modo que vi em alguns locais da web, fica muito extenso o código, tem algum modo como no meio acima para a versão atual do PHP?

Este e o código original que esta funcionando:

```
    class Elo{
        public $mmr;

        function fc_Elo(){
            if($this->mmr == 1300){
                echo "Teste".$this->mmr;
            }
            else{
                echo "1".$this->mmr;
            }
        }
    }

    $elo1=new Elo;
    $elo1->mmr = 1300;
    $elo1->fc_Elo();
```

Comment: Não entendi, vc quer saber se no php5 é possivel passar argumento no construtor?

Comment: No php4 para dar informação ao objeto e desta forma: $elo1=new Elo(1300, valor2, valor3); Gostaria de uma forma semelhante, ao invés de passar cada informação em cada linha, exemplo do atual: $elo1->mmr = 1300; $elo1->valor2 = xxx; $elo1->valor3 = yyy;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para passar valor no construtor, use o método [__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

```
class Elo{
   public $name;
   public $sexo;
   public $mmr;

    public function __construct($nome, $sexo){
       $this->name = $nome;
       $this->sexo = $sexo;        
    }

   public function fc_Elo(){
      if($this->mmr == 1300){
         echo "Teste".$this->mmr;
      }else{
         echo "1".$this->mmr;
      }
  }
}

$elo = new Elo('teste', '3x semana');
echo $elo->name .' - '. $elo->sexo;
```

Comment: Minha duvida e na parte de criar as informação de objetos, não em si na class. Por exemplo, tenho 2 public no class: public $name; public $sexo;  no caso eu quero saber se tem como ao invés de escrever $elo1=new Elo;     $elo1->name = "Alex";   $elo1->sexo = "Masculino"; que fica-se como no esquema do php4 $elo1=new Elo("Alex","Masculino");

Comment: @AlexBarros, sim é possível!

Comment: pode me explicar como?

Comment: É so definir os parametros no construtor. ou vc quer eles sejam variáveis?

Comment: variáveis nesta situação.