# Por que não posso declarar um atributo como objeto?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe `A` e estou criando uma classe `B`. Quero que um dos atributos de `B` seja um objeto de `A`.

Porque que a notação `public $objeto = new A();` não é correta?

Comment: Sabe o conceito de alocação de memória?

Comment: A linguagem não permite esse tipo de inicialização 'complexa'. Lembre que php é interpretado. Relacionada: [Instanciação de objetos em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153923/91)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não tenho muito conhecimento dessa parte da programação. Basicamente só conheço a parte da camada superficial.

Comment: Na verdade, a maior parte das linguagens passa essa inicialização para dentro do construtor, simplesmente a permite por simplificação sintática, como por exemplo o C# ou Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Porque que a notação public $objeto = new A(); não é correta?

Porque a linguagem não permite. Como diz a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), a inicialização deve ser o valor de um constante, isso é, deve-se ser possível conhecê-lo em tempo de compilação. Caso esse valor dependa de uma chamada de função, ou seja, uma expressão, ela não pode depender de nada que seja conhecido em tempo de execução (runtime).

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Como as demais respostas  comentaram, a solução para essas inicializações 'complexas' é criar um construtor próprio.

Esse código é inválido, pois a expressão depende da execução/chamada/criação da classe em tempo de execução.

```
class teste{
    static $a;
    static $b = 10;
    static $total = self::$a + self::$b;
}
```

Mas essa instrução funciona:

```
class teste{
    static $total = 10 + 51;
}
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/91)

Comment: Ah, tem isso também? Então tá, é tão fácil deixar fazer assim e transportar para o construtor automaticamente, como outras linguagens fazem. E mesmo sendo interpretado é necessário avaliar a classe toda de qualquer forma. Pelo menos ninguém pode negativar meu comentário por eu notar que PHP tem mais uma incompetência :D

Comment: Em PHP quando eu faço isso: `public $obj = new MinhaClasse();` a expressão `new MinhaClasse();` pode ser considerada uma função? Pelo que eu entendi, não funcionaria apenas para funções `public $obj = pegaValor();`.

Comment: @gato o construtor é um 'função especial' logo ele necessita de informação que não é conhecida em tempo de compilação.

Comment: @bigown negativar ninguém pode, no máximo sinalizar como ofensivo!11 :D. Imagino que seja meio caro fazer isso ou então simplesmente não compensa já que a vida do script é curta.

Comment: @rray um array usado na inicialização da propriedade de uma classe como este: `public $palavras = ["gato", "meow"];` poderia ser considerado uma *constante* ?

Comment: @gato essa aí sim, os valores dos elementos do array são conhecidos em tempo de 'compilação' nesse caso pq estão fixos. É constante no sentido de que o valor não vai mudar durante a 'compilação' depois na execução do script ele pode mudar sim.

Comment: @rray ou seja, é linguagem de script sem as facilidades de ser um script :D

Comment: @rray eu fiz um teste aqui com a função `array()` para inicializar o campo com um array: `public $palavras2 = array("gato", "meow");` e permitiu usar a função `array()`. Por que a função `array()` pode ser usada? O que ela tem de especial em relação as outras funções?

Comment: @gato `array()` não é uma função ele é um [language constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) ou seja essa instrução faz parte da linguagem, esse pessoal tem suas próprias regras (exceções) :P. Mais detalhes sobre o `array()` => [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func). Para você ter uma ideia recomendo a leitura da descrição do [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php). Eles mudaram ela um pouco antes era algo como: "o print não é um função mas funciona como uma exceto por não precisar de `()` na chamada.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas um complemento à outra resposta, você só consegue definir valores como variáveis, instâncias de classes e chamadas de funções a uma classe se utilizar  [o método __construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87619/4995).

No seu caso.

```
class B{

   protected $a;

   // Determina que o parâmetro passado será armazenado em 'a'
   // e deve ser uma instância da classe `A`.
   public function __construct (A $a) {
          $this->a = $a;
   }

   public function getA()
   {
       return $this->a;
   }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B($a);
```

Em alguns casos, pelo fato de ser necessário adicionar instâncias de determinadas classes em uma outras, usa-se muito o padrão de [injecção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%C3%A9-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia)