# Usar 'hoje' como valor default em método PHP

Tags: php

É possível fazer algo correspondente a isso com PHP (usar a data de hoje como default no parâmetro)?

```
class fiscalOBCharts
{
    private $exercise;

    public function exercise(string $exercise = date('d/m/Y')){
        $this->exercise = $exercise;        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim como não é possível inicializar propriedades de uma classe expressões ou chamadas de funções que dependam de algo com o código já rodando.

Uma opção seria já constutor definir essa data, armazenar na propriedade e mudar a assinatura do método deixando o valor padrão como nulo/vazio.

```
class fiscalOBCharts
{
    private $exercise;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->exercise = date('d/m/Y');
    }

    public function exercise(string $exercise=null){
        if(!empty($exercise)) $this->exercise = $exercise;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Relacionada:**

[Por que não posso declarar um atributo como objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219618/91)

Comment: Nem havia me passado na cabeça usar um construtor, solucionou meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme você pode ver na documentação, no tópico [Argumentos de funções](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments):

> O valor padrão precisa ser uma expressão constante, não (por exemplo)
>   uma variável, um membro de classe ou uma chamada de função.

Para o seu caso, você pode fazer:

```
class fiscalOBCharts
{
    private $exercise;

    public function exercise(string $exercise = ""){

        $this->exercise = ($exercise) ?: date('d/m/Y');        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assim também funcionária, mais achei utilizando um construtor mais 'bonito' e mais claro para a leitura.